# Annotations for the future on the candlestick chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, financial

I have script which draw candlestick chart. I added two annotations to this script. One is "Last data" which show last candle and the second annotations should show point in the future. But for some reason it is not visible on the picture. How can I make it visible? I was trying to change chart width and plt.axis values but didn't find solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import  DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator, HourLocator, \
     DayLocator, MONDAY
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo, candlestick,\
     plot_day_summary, candlestick2

from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Circle
el = Ellipse((2, -1), 0.5, 0.5)

# (Year, month, day) tuples suffice as args for quotes_historical_yahoo
date1 = ( 2013, 11, 10)
date2 = ( 2013, 12, 29)


mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)        # major ticks on the mondays
alldays    = DayLocator()              # minor ticks on the days
weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d')  # e.g., Jan 12
dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')      # e.g., 12

quotes = quotes_historical_yahoo('INTC', date1, date2)

if len(quotes) == 0:
    raise SystemExit

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

candlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.6)

ax.xaxis_date()
plt.setp( plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

dt = quotes[0][0]

ax.annotate(
                'Last data',
                xy=(dt+16, 24),
                xytext=(dt+3, 25),
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='simple', fc="0.6", ec="none", patchB=el, connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0.3", facecolor='black')
        )

ax.annotate(
                'Future',
                xy=(dt+19, 24.5),
                xytext=(dt+2, 23.7),
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='simple', fc="0.6", ec="none", patchB=el, connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0.3", facecolor='black')
        )

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

[image: annotations]

Comment: are you looking for `set_xlim`?

Comment: Yes. It looks like set_xlim is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the xlimit on your graph:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([start_data, end_date])
plt.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code as (was) written works for me on OS X, Python 2.7.5.

Both the 'Future' and 'Last data' arcs are drawn and labelled.

If you count the candlesticks, there are only 13 - which you also see if you add a print statement:

```
quotes = quotes_historical_yahoo('INTC', date1, date2)
print len(quotes)
```

As your code indicates, everything past the 28th Nov is a 'future date' so there is no data for it -- thus the return from quotes_historical_yahoo() only has 13 days of quotes (plus apparently some gaps for the weekends).

You can't annotate points past the 28th November because they aren't in the plotted data, so the call fails.

Comment: I have updated the code. The xy is now (dt+19, 24.5) for the second annotation.

Comment: I know that I have no data there. But I want to work around this and create this annotation.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be added as workaround:

```
line = Line2D(
        xdata=(dt+19, dt+19),
        ydata=(24.5, 24.5), )

ax.add_line(line) ax.autoscale_view()
```

Annotation can be created now:

[image]